# Azure Data Factory Lookup Previously Working Now Failing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have a Lookup Shape pointed to a snowflake data set that is defined from a snowflake linked service.

Both the Linked Service and Dataset pass their connection tests.

However when invoking a lookup shape using this dataset I am now getting the following error:

**No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.**

On adding a *use warehouse whname* command before the SQL query I get an error. So merely adding this statement is probably not the resolution to this issue.

This was a previously working lookup shape, there have been backend configuration changes.

What is the most likely cause of this syntactical change?

Comment: What is the error message, when added `use warehouse <whname>`

Comment: Are you sure the WH still exists? This could happen if the WH was dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because you have not granted access to the Warehouse to the role:

```
GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE my_warehouse TO ROLE my_role;
```

Please try if this helps.

Comment: Hello, that is what appears to have happened behind the scenes.  When I retried my pipeline this morning it is back to working!